# Define owner after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Walls belong to users through a WallAssignments association.

```
class Wall < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :wall_assignments
    has_many :users, :through => :wall_assignments
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :wall_assignments
    has_many :walls, :through => :wall_assignments
end

class WallAssignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :wall
end
```

In the create action, I'm associating the current user with the new wall record.

```
def create
    @wall = Wall.new
    @wall.wall_assignments.build(user_id: current_user.id)

    if @wall.save
        redirect_to @wall
    else
        redirect_to current_user
    end
end
```

However, aside from allowing many users to belong to the wall, I'd like to have one user (the user who created it) own the wall.

I'm attempting something like this:

```
class Wall < ApplicationRecord
    after_create { owner }

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :wall_assignments
    has_many :users, :through => :wall_assignments

private

    def owner
        self.owner = Wall.users.first
    end
end
```

Eventually, I'd like to be able to call `@wall.owner.name` and `@wall.owner.id` in my views.

Comment: Is this just a test or you actually want to assign the first user in your db as the owner of the wall? If you want that you need to say `self.owner = Wall.users.first` and not `Wall.owner` which is nothing (assuming owner exists in your wall table)

Comment: @colmtuite: can you please add all association in question? owner will be user only or its separate table of a database? Is it like, the `wall has many users through wall_assignments` and `wall has one owner`? where owner and user are different entity?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting `undefined method `users' for`. Should it be Wall.user_assignments.first.user? Or something like that?

Comment: @bunty I've updated the question, thanks! Yes, wall has many users through wall_assignments and wall has one owner...but owner and user are the same entity.

Comment: No, you need to use object of wall to get users. As you written code in model itself, current record will be available. So it should be `self.user_assignments.first.user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to have has_many(as users) and has_one(as owner) with same table User.

In this scenario, your Wall model will be:

```
class Wall < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :owner_id
    has_many :wall_assignments
    has_many :users, :through => :wall_assignments
end
```

You need to add `owner_id` column in walls table.
So when you create Wall record, it will

```
class Wall < ApplicationRecord
    after_create { add_owner }

    private    
    def add_owner
        self.update_column(:owner_id, self.users.first.id) if self.users.present?
    end
end
```

You can also modify controller's create code(I assumed, create method will get called only once.)

```
def create
    @wall = Wall.new(wall_params)
    @wall.owner_id = current_user.id
    @wall.wall_assignments.build(user_id: current_user.id)
    if @wall.save
        redirect_to @wall
    else
        redirect_to current_user
    end
end
```

with this, you don't need to add `after_create` callback in Wall model.
And then you can call `@wall.owner.name` and `@wall.owner_id`

Comment: I've added the `owner_id` column to the `Wall` model. I've updated the Wall model with the `foreign_key`. I'm using the `create` action approach you suggested. However, when I call `@wall.owner.name` I'm getting an error - `private method "owner" called for`

Comment: Please see updated answer. We used same name for method to add owner and we have same name for has_one association. So when we called for @wall.owner, Rails looked for owner private method. Please do correction and let me know

Comment: I'm not sure what you updated in your answer? I've copied your code and still can't get it working...I'm getting the same error

Comment: With the `after_create` model approach, I'm getting an error `undefined method "id" for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I'm seeding all of this data. Is it because of the order of the data in my seeds.rb? Currently it goes users, then walls, then wall_assignments...I'm not sure it can be in any other order?

Comment: Hi, while seeding data, how do you assign user to walls?

Comment: `WallAssignment.create! wall_id: '1', user_id: '1'`

Comment: ohk... JUST OF SEEDING DATA do this:  comment this line form wall.rb `after_create { add_owner }` and `private` keyword. Now seed the data. Add if condition in add_owner methods as `if self.users.present?`. I have updated ans for this. After this from rails console fire this query `Wall.each{|w| w.add_owner }` this will add an owner to wall data.

Comment: I'm getting console error `NoMethodError: undefined method "each" for Wall (call "Wall.connection" to establish a connection):Class`

Comment: do this `Wall.all.each{|w| w.add_owner }`